# MYSQL - How to group by with condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

[Here's an example of the tables and outputs I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEM9Y.png)

I want to group by by no reg with condition, status = 0 but if in table activity there is no status = 0 then that will be selected is with biggest id

Answer (score 0):

You may only need this query.

```
Select no_reg, location from activities where status = 0
```

Check the result and run another query.

```
if (result == null){ //for example run the query below

Select no_reg, location from activities desc limit 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image what you want is activities of the equipment i believe

for example if you want to check the equipment A1 Malaysia should be list or one with biggest status will be listed i believe

if thats what you want here it is

```
SELECT no_reg,MAX(status) FROM activities a,equipment e on e.no_reg=a.no_reg where e.no_reg='A1' group by a.no_reg
```

i believe this is the solution you are expecting